# Please say this integral is correct of $f(x) = e^{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, exponential-function

> $$\int{e^{x^2} dx}$$

I have this in school many year ago but I forget everything.. and now I don't believed I need it again!

A friend say I need replace exponent with a variable I make so I can make this task easier?

I try like that:

$a = x^2$, $$a' = 2x \Leftrightarrow \frac{da}{dx} = 2x \Leftrightarrow da = 2x \text{ }dx \Leftrightarrow dx = \frac{1}{2x} \text{ } da$$

Now I change all in task with what I write above:

$$\int{e^{x^2} dx} = \int{e^a \cdot \frac{1}{2x} \text{ } da} = \frac{1}{2x}\int{e^a \text{ } da} = \frac{1}{2x} \cdot e^a+c$$

Now put old value in:

$$\int{e^{x^2} dx = \frac{1}{2x} \cdot e^{2x} + c}$$

When I want check solution, online give me the result:

[image]

But I don't know this meaning.. There is better method for solve? This is very much time for solving. I think the method I use, if correct, is used for more complicated exponents? Because this exponent is little.

Comment: This integral is impossible to determine using elementary means. The issue with your answer is you can't simply pull out the $\frac{1}{2x}$. For evidence that this is the case, try differentiating your result. What do you get?

Comment: This integral does not exist as elementary fucntion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your specific mistake is in the third line, when you write $\int e^a \frac{1}{2x} da = \frac{1}{2x}\int e^ada$. Because $a$ is a function of $x$, you cannot pull it out. To see that your answer is wrong, try differentiating $\frac{1}{2x}e^{2x} + C$ and observing what you get. It's a theorem that you cannot express $\int e^{x^2} dx$ in terms of elementary functions.